# Não recebo retorno de Json no Ajax com PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, json

não consigo sair do lugar, o que está errado? Não recebo o retorno do Json no Ajax.

cadastrarCliente.php

Ajax.js

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "crud/insere.php",
    data: dados,
    success: function(data) {

        var objeto = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(objeto.id);

     }
});
return false;
```

insere.php

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$telefone1 = $_POST['telefone1'];
$operadora1 = $_POST['operadora1'];
$telefone2 = $_POST['telefone2'];
$operadora2 = $_POST['operadora2'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$cidade = $_POST['idCidade'];
$observacao = $_POST['obs'];
$dataCadastro = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

if(empty($cidade)){
    $cidade = '0';
}

$select = "INSERT INTO Cliente(nome, telefone1, telefone2, operadora1,  operadora2, 
           email, idCidade, observacao, dataCadastro) 
           VALUES ('$nome', '$telefone1', '$telefone2', '$operadora1', '$operadora2', '$email', '$cidade','$observacao', '$dataCadastro')";
$conexao = conexao();           
$PDO=$conexao->prepare($select);
$PDO->execute();

$select = "SELECT id FROM Cliente WHERE email='$email'";
$PDO=$conexao->prepare($select);
$PDO->execute();
$obj = $PDO -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$arr = array('id' => $obj->id);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Código fonte completo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esta linha não é precisa pois já disseste que é type:json, `var objeto = JSON.parse(data);`. Em termos de segurança da base de dados inserir os valores assim é muito inseguro, mas talvez estejas só a testar.

Comment: Mesmo assim,não acontece nada, nem no console do browser.

Comment: Cara, se tiveres um exemplo que funcione e poderes me enviar, ficaria muito grato.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, falta declarar o header.

Na penúltima linha do seu arquivo php coloca isso :

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```